# Question linking on Meta SF and Meta SU

Tags: support, status-completed, gravatar, per-site-meta, meta-serverfault

All the gravatars on meta SF (and mostly on meta SU I see) are anonymous right now.  Are they just hardcoded to be anonymous temporarily?  Is it just me?

**EDIT:**
Seems to be just in the question lists.  They show up on the Users page.

**EDIT 2:**
So it's been over a day, new questions are working fine.  It's obviously an abandoned question thing.  Crickets are starting to chirp and dust winds are brewing up on Meta SF, which admittedly is not all that unexpected given the non-existent velocity of SF questions here.

Any update on when the SF and SU metas are going to get some reconnection love?

Comment: Umm, I'd rather not talk about your personal problems.

Comment: Belongs on meta.serverfault? :)

Comment: @mmyers: oh, you'll hear them.

Comment: @Juan: **smack**

Comment: Give it at least an hour.

Comment: @random: will do, cheers.

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58201/are-the-questions-and-answers-that-have-been-migrated-to-super-users-and-server ; technically this one was first but the diamond mod answer is on the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on this tonight - [Are the questions and answers that have been migrated to Super User's and Server Fault's metas going to get reassociated with our accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58201/are-the-questions-and-answers-that-have-been-migrated-to-super-users-and-server/58252#58252)

Answer (score 5):

It's because the users have not actually registered there. If you check the Users list, you'll notice it is very small. I'm on Meta.SF because I still have my SF cookie, but I'm logged out of SU so I didn't register my Meta.SU account as a result.

Once a user logs in to either the parent or the meta site, it will set that user's account and reassociate all owned posts to that account. It's not unlike when a post is migrated from any one site to another where the user has not registered yet.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't associating people with their accounts or their gravatar.

Comment: Yeah, what @Lance said.  I got logged in just great, no associate needed.  I'm in the user list on metaSF, everything looks great except the gravatars.

Comment: My Meta.SF account got associated with its parent SF account and gravatar when I logged in. Consequently, my Meta.SU hasn't because I haven't done anything to trigger the association. If you check any of those posts, for example, http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1144/su-tag-merge-request-microsoft-word-and-word, you'll notice that the user basically doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Grace: mine exists on metaSF.  See my edit in the question, seems to be a problem in the question lists.

Comment: @Grace: I don't see your gravatar in the metaSU question you link too, either.

Comment: @squillman That's because [that user account doesn't exist yet](http://meta.superuser.com/users/37191/ccomet). I'm saying that it's not a Gravatar issue - it's a combination of the fact that most of the users aren't registered yet, as well as some posts that themselves haven't been associated yet.

Comment: @Grace: Ok, I'm with you now.  Been a long day and the whole "reassociate all owned posts" thing just registered in my brain...

Comment: Pre re-calc: 8812. Post: 8757