# Are the questions and answers that have been migrated to Super User's and Server Fault's metas going to get reassociated with our accounts?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, meta-serverfault

Title says it all, really.

Questions tagged [`[superuser]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superuser) and [`[serverfault]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/servfault) were copied(?) to their respective metas ([Meta Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/), [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/)) but are "orphaned" in their new home.

Is there going to be a mass reassociation at some point, or is this `[status-bydesign]`?

Comment: that would result in a reponomy-crisis since that meta-rep is overridden by the parent...

Comment: @Tobias - it's for ownership of the posts. The rep is immaterial.

Comment: I wasn't *that* serious about it. But I assume it will be automatically re-associated as soon as the OP logs in, since at least [this question](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/274/reduce-community-wiki-force-threshold-to-15-answers-on-superuser) by Jeff links to his meta.SU-account

Comment: @Tobias - I'm already logged in a visited both metas but haven't "regained" my questions. I've tried logging out and log back in again but still no questions/answers in my profile.

Comment: We've mapped all the posts that we could, based on users that have been created on the destination sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some background - when a question and its answers are migrated to another site and the owning user accounts don't exist, we can only show owners' display names.  When users then create accounts on the destination site, we have a method for mapping up these orphaned posts.

However, this mapping method has a bad assumption - that the originating question is closed.  When we mass-migrated these meta questions, we didn't close them first!

Don't worry, we'll get this fixed; post ownership will be restored.

Comment: Thanks - that's all I wanted to know. But it does lead onto a supplementary question - are the original questions going to get closed?

Comment: @Chris The original questions were deleted, I believe. For example, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56052/su-tag-merge-request-microsoft-word-and-word?noredirect=1